# Java Rest API cannot recognise ID in DB

Tags: java, postgresql

I am trying to create basic crud app with java and springboot 3.

Everything is working just fine, get, delete, update, post.

But when I add items into my DB manually then I am not able to post anymore because I get error message that id already exits. It seems like my program is unable to see items added manually.

So just to summary it, Post request is working fine but whenever I add some other items into DB manually I have error about existing key.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EefL.png)

this is my entity

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQAFm.png)

db

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppMmO.png)

I tried to. change generated values, I tried @Sequence generators nothing is working

Answer (score 0):

the answer to that is to use postgres' nextval('sequence_name') when adding something manually

```
Insert into employees(id,first_name, last_name, email)
values(nextval('my_sequence'), 'Joe', 'Doe', 'joe.doe@email.com')
```

That way next time you will use POST, the sequence's value will be updated